# How to use requiereJS to import local imput json file?

Tags: javascript, json, file, input

I want to load a json from local input file to my js script.

The json is imported and I can get the file object, but I can't properly get the JSON and parse it to a JS Object

I tried to use RequiereJS which seems to be the best and quickest solution but I can't make this line to work

```
require(['json!someFile.json'], function(data){

})
```

Here is my input in HTML :

```html
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" onchange="loadFile(this.file) accept="application/json">
```

And here my js file :

```
function loadFile(file) {
    var myJson;
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    require(['json!'+url+''], function(data){
        myJson = data;
    }
}
```

Or this :

```
require(['json!'+file+''], function(data){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax function from jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url: "data.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(){
        alert("json not found");
    }
});
```

Note: You need to have the file in server then only it will work.